# openshot not launching (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: openshot

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and Openshot video editor is not launching, I tried removing and reinstalling and installing PPA.

This is what I get from the terminal:

```
Loaded modules from: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:             Sun Apr 16 17:09:43 2023            
INFO app:               Starting new session              
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:             OpenShot (version 3.1.0)            
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app: openshot-qt version: 3.1.0
INFO app: libopenshot version: 0.2.5
INFO app: platform: Linux-5.19.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
INFO app: processor: x86_64
INFO app: machine: x86_64
INFO app: python version: 3.10.6
INFO app: qt5 version: 5.15.3
INFO app: pyqt5 version: 5.15.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py", line 196, in main
    app = OpenShotApp(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/app.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.project = project_data.ProjectDataStore()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/project_data.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.new()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/project_data.py", line 291, in new
    profile = self.get_profile(profile_desc=default_profile_desc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/project_data.py", line 341, in get_profile
    if legacy_profile and legacy_profile.Key() == temp_profile.Key():
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'Key'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openshot-qt", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('openshot-qt==3.1.0', 'gui_scripts', 'openshot-qt')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py", line 198, in main
    app.show_errors()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show_errors'
INFO app:             OpenShot's session ended            
INFO app:             Sun Apr 16 17:09:43 2023            
INFO app: ================================================
Sentry is attempting to send 1 pending error messages
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You do not install a PPA it is simply a pointer to where the software is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the AppImage instead. Download it from https://www.openshot.org/nl/download/ . It should detect that you have a Linux version and offer to download the AppImage version.

An AppImage is basically a sort of zip-file containing all depedencies and usually works without any problems.

When downloading, put it in a folder of your choice (rather not keep it in `~/Downloads`. Then in a terminal make it executable:

```bash
martin@Jupiter:/mnt/ssd/AppImages$ chmod a+x OpenShot-v3.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

Then create a Desktop shortcut file in `/home/<your username>/.local/share/applications` using e.g. `gedit` or the editor of your choice, and name it `openshot.desktop`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=OpenShot Video Editor
GenericName=Video Ediging
Comment=Create your own videos
Exec=/mnt/ssd/AppImages/OpenShot-v3.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
Icon=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Notice that the `Icon` part is empty. You could search for an icon of OpenShot, put in the same directory and then point to it (full path is recommended) in the `Icon=` line. For instance this link. [wiki](https://www.openshot.org/static/files/user-guide/index.html)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=OpenShot Video Editor
GenericName=Video Editing
Comment=Create your own videos
Exec=/mnt/ssd/AppImages/OpenShot-v3.1.0-x86_64.AppImage
Icon=/mnt/ssd/AppImages/openshot-arrow.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Afterwards just open the applications menu in UBuntu and start typing 'openshot' and it should appear.